# Simple CORS does not work (even though it should)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I'm trying to hack my back-end, which exposes a REST API. The worst thing that can happen to my database according to firefox CORS policy is that I can create a new object with POST request, as it does not need a preflight. This is the simple code (I'm running it via jsfiddle, but it shouldn't mean a thing)

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/company", true);
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
xhttp.send('{description:"This company was added by pure hacking"}');
```

But I'm getting an error in the console:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/company"
```

Comment: jsFiddle uses SSL, which means it won't load content that isn't `https://`. As you're connecting to localhost, you should be using a local webserver instead.

Comment: A better test would be to use a curl request.  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{description:"This company was added by pure hacking"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/company  Also testing against your local host and not external facing isn't going to be very useful...

Comment: But `curl` cannot transfer the cookies in the browser. It's all about user's cookies (csrf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not because of SOP, its a mixed content error, that is making an http request on a https page.
jsfiddle defaults to https but allows http, but only on saved fiddles.

Change the url of your fiddle to use http instead of https

Comment: Ok now it works (except I'm getting unauthorized on my page and I need to investigate why)